# Relationship with user condition

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a follow system that works like Twitter's follow (you follow other people and get updates from them).

I have this relationship set in my `User.php` model:

```
public function follows()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Follow');
}
```

This obviously gets all records of users who follow this person.

However, when displaying the person's profile page, I want to get a relationship that checks if a follow record exists given the user ID.

Something like:

```
public function userFollow()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Follow')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
}
```

So now my profile page query looks like this:

```
$user = User::where('username', $username)
    ->with('userFollow')
    ->first();
```

This works as long as the user is logged in. If the user **isn't** logged in, the page gives me this error:

> ErrorException in User.php line 28: Trying to get property of
>   non-object

How do I fix this? What is the proper way of using conditions in relationships?

Answer (score 0):

This is because if user is logged out then Auth::user() is null, because user session has ended. Auth::user() is no more object, so you can't get the id from a null object.

Here you can do something like that

```
public function userFollow()
{
  $userId = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->id : $this->id; 
  return $this->hasOne('App\Follow')->where('user_id', $userId);
}
```

then it will not look for authenticated user, it will just get the particular user table's id.

Comment: That works if the user is logged out, but it gets no record when I'm logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of using conditions in relationships is using [Constraining eager loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

```
public function userFollow()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Follow');
}
```

And,

```
if(Auth::check())
{
       $user = User::where('username', $username)
             ->with(['userFollow'=>function($query)
                {
                    $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
                }]);
             ->first();
}
```